# Codeigniter page cache when using custom _output method

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I would like to cache my pages, which could be done by using:

```
$this->output->cache(n)
```

As in the documentation, i could use a custom output method in my controller, named **_output**.

The problem is, when I create this _output method in my controller, **it doesn't create any cache file**, only displays the output. I looked into the Output core class, and as I see if it's not find any method with **_output**, it just **echo** the content.

They have this in the documentation, to use in my _output:

```
if ($this->output->cache_expiration > 0)
{
   $this->output->_write_cache($output);
}
```

But cache_expiration is not accessible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **2** ways of solving this,

1. you can edit the core files and make it the `cache_expiration` to
   **public** instead of **protected** and mess with the core files (**DIRTY WAY**)
2. or you can extend the `CI_Output` class (**BETTER**)

Create a file name it `MY_Output.php` in your `application/core` the `MY_` prefix is found on the `$config['subclass_prefix']` option in your `application/config/config.php` file.,

then put this little piece of code:

```
class MY_Output Extends CI_Output{

    public $the_public_cache_expiration_ = 0;

    public function get_cache_expiration()
    {
        $this->cache_expiration_ = $this->cache_expiration;
    }
}
```

What we are  doing is we are extending the `CI_Output` class and adding our very own method, when the method `get_cache_expiration()` is called it will assign the `cache_expiration` to `the_public_cache_expiration_`, use it on your `_output`.

test it using this:

```
public function _output($output)
    {
        $this->output->get_cache_expiration();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->output->the_public_cache_expiration_);//get only our cache expiration
        echo '<hr>';
        print_r($this->output);//print the whole Output class
    }
```

benefits:

1. We did no mess with the core files.
2. we can add more functionality later to our child class.

here is the basic `_output` method in use

```
public function _output($output)

    {
        $this->output->get_cache_expiration();

        if($this->output->cache_expiration_ > 0)
        {
            $this->output->_write_cache($output);
        }

        echo $output;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's made it!